# How to kill a running process in compilation buffer in MS Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, process, compilation-mode

I have tried using `M-x kill-compilation` and it doesn't kill the process (on Microsoft Windows). It just sends `^C`, which makes my script to retry.

When I try to `M-x kill-buffer` on the compilation buffer it kills the process and closes the buffer.

I want the process killed without closing the compilation buffer. How do I send a stronger kill signal in my compilation buffer?

Comment: I have found `helm-list-emacs-process` which lists all the process and then I can kill it. It might be useful to bind it to something.

Comment: For people who do not use `helm`, the built-in method to list Emacs process is with `M-x list-processes`.  However, that will not list processes running in the background (outside of Emacs).

Comment: @lawlist there's `proced` for that.